# Ignore addresses from mailing list mail with BBDB in Emacs

Tags: emacs, email-headers, bbdb, bbdb-3

I'd like to configure bbdb to *not* auto-notice addresses in mailing list mail. I'm trying to use the `X-Mailing-List` and `X-Mailman-Version` headers, since those seem to be consistently present on all the mailing lists I read, but it doesn't seem to be working (i.e. bbdb still offers to save email addresses from mails containing those headers)... What am I doing wrong?

```
(setq bbdb-ignore-message-alist
      '((("X-Mailman-Version" "X-Mailing-List") . ".*")))
```

By the way, I'm using [`bbdbv3`](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/bbdb/).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my copy of the BBDB manual, it seems that you need to set `bbdb/mail-auto-create-p` (setting it to `bbdb-ignore-some-messages-hook`) and then you want `bbdb-ignore-some-messages-alist` (note the "-some"). See [section 1.7.3: Predefined Hooks](http://bbdb.sourceforge.net/bbdb.html#SEC61).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using [`bbdbv3`](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/bbdb/) and that seems to be bbdbv2-specific...